# Unable to activate Lizard analyzer [vscode]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, linter, cpplint

Installing the C/C++ Advanced Lint extension in vscode offers supported Static Analyzers. [lizard](https://pypi.org/project/lizard/) is amongst the list. I have lizard installed successfully via `pip install lizard`. But I still get the following error

[image]

The options in settings related to lizard are to either enable or override the feature
[image]

Not sure how I can get this to work. CppCheck worked fine after installing it via `scoop install cppcheck`

Comment: this question maybe help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45160650/why-do-i-get-error-messages-like-unable-to-activate-xx-analyzer-in-vscode